# What does target_link_directories() do in CMake?

Tags: cmake, linker, static-libraries

I'm learning standard CMake functions, and after reading the documentation, I still have this question. They say

*"Specifies the paths in which the linker should search for libraries when linking a given target"*

But I don't really get how linker can look for libraries, when I use `target_link_libraries()` which already knows where my libraries are.

Thank you.

Comment: I have yet to see a valid use of `target_link_directories` in new code. If you're working with targets, it should not be necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The directories you pass to this command are used you pass something that's not a cmake target to `target_link_libraries`.

From the [docs of `target_link_libraries`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html)

> This command has several signatures as detailed in subsections below. All of them have the general form
>
> `target_link_libraries(<target> ... <item>... ...)`
>
> [...]
>
> Each `<item>` may be:
>
> - **A library target name:** [...]
> - **A full path to a library file:** [...]
> - **A plain library name:** The generated link line will ask the linker to search for the library (e.g. foo becomes -lfoo or foo.lib).
>   [...]
> - ...

The third option ("A plain library name") is the one where `target_link_directories` gets relevant; if the linker does not find the library by default, you need to add provide the path via `target_link_directories` (or by similar means of modifying the `LINK_DIRECTORIES` target property).

Comment: I would add that you should not use the second or third options in new code and should instead use `find_library` to create an imported target if a native CMake package or Find module is not available.